# An exception is thrown after a row is deleted from a strongly typed DataSet?

Tags: ado.net, datagridview, linq-to-objects, strongly-typed-dataset, delete-row

I am using .NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have three tables:

```
Companies (PK CompanyID) 
Addresses (PK AddressID, FK CompanyID) 
ContactPersons (PK ContactPersonID, FK CompanyID)
```

CompanyID is assigned manually by the users. The other IDs are auto-generated. Companies has a one-to-many relationship with ContactPerson. I have set any changes to cascade.

I display all records in Companies in a DataGridView and when a row is clicked, the corresponding records in ContactPersons are displayed in a second DataGridView.

Then I delete a row from the table ContactPersons with:

```
DataRow row = m_SoldaCompaniesFileDataSet.ContactPersons.Rows.Find(this.m_CurrentContactPerson.ContactPersonID);
row.Delete();
```

And when I try to query the table with to create a datasource to populate the DataGridView:

```
var dataRows_ContactPersons = from row in this.m_SoldaCompaniesFileDataSet.ContactPersons
                              where row.CompanyID == companyID
                              select new
                              {
                                 ContactPersonID = row.ContactPersonID,
                                 CompanyID = row.CompanyID,
                                 NameFirst = row.NameFirst,
                                 NameLast = row.NameLast,
                                 PhoneNumber = row.PhoneNumber,
                                 EmailAddress = row.EmailAddress,
                                 Position = row.Position
                              };
```

I receive DeletedRowInaccessibleException. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Actually the exception comes from that autogenerated code for the typed DataSet:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
            public int CompanyID {
                get {
                    try {
                        return ((int)(this[this.tableContactPersons.CompanyIDColumn])); // <<<--- DeletedRowInaccessibleException
                    }
                    catch (global::System.InvalidCastException e) {
                        throw new global::System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column \'CompanyID\' in table \'ContactPersons\' is DBNull.", e);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out shortly after writing the above question (although it took me over a day altogether):

```
var dataRows_ContactPersons = from row in this.m_SoldaCompaniesFileDataSet.ContactPersons
                              where row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted && row.CompanyID == companyID
                              select new
                              {
                                   ContactPersonID = row.ContactPersonID,
                                   CompanyID = row.CompanyID,
                                   NameFirst = row.NameFirst,
                                   NameLast = row.NameLast,
                                   PhoneNumber = row.PhoneNumber,
                                   EmailAddress = row.EmailAddress,
                                   Position = row.Position
                              };
```

It is necessary to exclude the deleted rows from the Linq query by doing this check:

```
row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted
```